# Netty server could not connected

Tags: netty

I write a tcp server sample named echo,but it could not connected by remote client.
Here is my code:

```
public class EchoServer {
private int port = 8888;

public void startServer() throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new EchoDecoder());
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new EchoHandler());
                    }
                }).option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128).childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);

        ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.bind(port).sync();
        System.out.println("bind completed.");
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        System.out.println("channel closed.");
    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        System.out.println("Closed");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new EchoServer().startServer();
}
```

}

Waiting for your answer,thanks advance.

Run environment:windows7 64bit

netty version:4.0.34

Comment: maybe check windows firewall ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I update my java run time environment then this sample run well.